# Is this system object pointer code at all possible in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, swift

I was pointed to this objc snippet [from WWDC 14](http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/508xxfvaehrll14/508/508_camera_capture_manual_controls.pdf?dl=1), but I work on a Swift project.

```
CMIOObjectPropertyAddress   prop    = {
    kCMIOHardwarePropertyAllowScreenCaptureDevices,
    kCMIOObjectPropertyScopeGlobal,
    kCMIOObjectPropertyElementMaster
};
UInt32                      allow   = 1;

CMIOObjectSetPropertyData(kCMIOObjectSystemObject, &prop, 0, NULL, sizeof(allow), &allow);
```

I then tried rewriting to Swift:

```
var prop : CMIOObjectPropertyAddress {
    kCMIOHardwarePropertyAllowScreenCaptureDevices
    kCMIOObjectPropertyScopeGlobal
    kCMIOObjectPropertyElementMaster
}

var allow:UInt32 = 1
CMIOObjectSetPropertyData(kCMIOObjectSystemObject, &prop, 0, nil, sizeof(UInt32), &allow)
```

But it doesn't even validate. I don't know how to translate the `CMIOObjectPropertyAddress` struct. Xcode says

> /Users/mortenjust/Dropbox/hack/learning/screenrec/screenrec/deleteme.swift:32:61:
>   Cannot assign to a get-only property 'prop'

Comment: Oh, forgot to add, I got it working by bridging an objective-c class that does only the stuff above. I want to **avoid** this, as bridging headers make Xcode autocompletion incredibly slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A C struct translates as a Swift struct. Use the implicit memberwise initializer:

```
    var prop = CMIOObjectPropertyAddress(
        mSelector: UInt32(kCMIOHardwarePropertyAllowScreenCaptureDevices),
        mScope: UInt32(kCMIOObjectPropertyScopeGlobal),
        mElement: UInt32(kCMIOObjectPropertyElementMaster))
```

The cool part is when you type `CMIOObjectPropertyAddress(`, code completion gives you the rest.

Answer (score 3):

You're right, just got it running right this second. Turns out I also had to correct for some of the types. Here's the complete translation:

```
        var prop = CMIOObjectPropertyAddress(
        mSelector: CMIOObjectPropertySelector(kCMIOHardwarePropertyAllowScreenCaptureDevices),
        mScope: CMIOObjectPropertyScope(kCMIOObjectPropertyScopeGlobal),
        mElement: CMIOObjectPropertyElement(kCMIOObjectPropertyElementMaster))

    var allow : UInt32 = 1
    var dataSize : UInt32 = 4
    var zero : UInt32 = 0
    CMIOObjectSetPropertyData(CMIOObjectID(kCMIOObjectSystemObject), &prop, zero, nil, dataSize, &allow)

    var session = AVCaptureSession()
    session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh

    var devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices()
    for device in AVCaptureDevice.devices() {
        println(device)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for reporting back. Could be useful to others! (Swift numerics are maddening, aren't they?)